# Calling R from C from R in mcmc

Tags: c, r, mcmc

So I have to run large mcmc's which are not feasible in R. Hence I am writing out the loops in  C and calling it from R using .C

However, within this loop, I occasionally have sampling steps or modeling steps for which there are standard packages in R. Coding these things in C from scratch would be overkill for me.

Which is why I would like to call R functions here. I am going to do this using "8.1 Embedding R under Unix-alikes" in "writing R extensions".

So it becomes, R being embedded in C, which is in itself a .C call from R. Is this approach OK in terms of

- simplicity, or is there an more elegant framework ?
- stability (R calling C, which calls R)
- scalability (R calling C, which calls R), I will be running multiple such mcmc samplers on amazon ?
- memory usage?

I am only interested in R embedding in C (not c++). Speed is very important to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "OK?"

Comment: Fair point. Added my emphasis on simplicity of the framework.

Comment: look at package Rcpp you can write CPP code call it from R and you have access to R fonctions within CPP

Comment: Further expanded on my points.

Comment: Thanks @statquant. Will look in to that. I was however hoping to do it in C.

Comment: Well I said C++ but there is nothing preventing you from using C instead C++ (I think)

Comment: True. Its just that I have started doing fairly basic stuff in C and was a bit apprehensive in jumping to OOP now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do precisely this in the mcmc package on CRAN, http://cran.us.r-project.org/web/packages/mcmc/index.html .  That link includes way to download the source code.

This package implements the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.  Specifically, C code handles running the MH loop, but calls a user supplied R function to evaluate the log unnormalized target density at each iteration, it will also call a user supplied output function.

I've run this code with very large models and datasets, so it's definitely feasible to run "large" MCMC estimations in R with this approach.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I am going through the R Extensions manual now and checked your source codes too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please tell us a bit more on which C functions use R functions within the mcmc package?