# Is there a way of passing an R function object (`CLOSXP`) to C level code and register it as a callback?

Tags: r, c

### Problem

I am wrapping a fraction of the [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/) C library in R.

One functionality I'd like to wrap is the registration of callbacks.

For example, to set an error callback in C, GLFW provides the function:

```
GLFWerrorfun glfwSetErrorCallback(GLFWerrorfun callback)
```

whose callback signature is:

```
void callback_name(int error_code, const char* description)
```

Could you provide any pointers on how to allow the user to define a function in R, i.e. a `CLOSXP` object, and pass it, and, somehow, get it transformed to a C function passable to `glfwSetErrorCallback()`.

I am looking for a plain R's C internal API solution, i.e., and not something based on Rcpp, please.

I have read this [blog post](https://www.cytel.com/blog/harnessing-r-api-to-extend-software-applications) , and I got the feeling I could perhaps use some combination of `Rf_install()` and `R_tryEval()`... but on the other hand, in [Hadley's R internals](https://github.com/hadley/r-internals/blob/ea892fa79bbffe961e78dbe9c90ce4ca3bf2d9bc/symbols.md), I only see `Rf_install()` associated with symbols (`SYMSXP`). I could not find much information about `Rf_install()` either except for some appearances in code snippets in [An external pointer example](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#An-external-pointer-example) in *Writing R Extensions*.

### Edit

After reading the answer to [Calling R from C from R in mcmc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480592/calling-r-from-c-from-r-in-mcmc), I think might be able to register an R function as a callback if I resort to using a global variable, `SEXP rcallback`:

#### R code

```
#' @export
glfw_set_error_callback <- function(callback) {
  .Call("glfw_set_error_callback_", callback)
}
```

#### C code

```
SEXP rcallback;
static void error_cb(int error, const char* description)
{
  SEXP r_error = PROTECT(Rf_ScalarInteger(error));
  SEXP r_description = PROTECT(Rf_mkString(description));

  SEXP call = PROTECT(Rf_lang3(rcallback, r_error, r_description));
  // `call` is evaluated for its side effects, so no need to store and/or
  // PROTECT the result from its evaluation.
  Rf_eval(call, R_GlobalEnv);

  UNPROTECT(3);
  return;
}

SEXP glfw_set_error_callback_(SEXP callback) {

  rcallback = callback;
  glfwSetErrorCallback(error_cb);

  return R_NilValue;
}
```

Comment: Your "and not something based on Rcpp, please" is a little off. There is only one interface, offered by R as a C function `.Call(...)` taking zero to several `SEXP` and returning a `SEXP`.  `Rcpp` "simply" helps with a lof of conversion tedium, with build automation, and of course offers a number of helpful wrappers such as `Rcpp::Function()` -- but at its core uses the same interface you are looking at. As for calling and calling back,  we have some worked examples for Rcpp but those wrap around external pointers so you may want to concentrate on that too.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mean to suggest that Rcpp is something else. I know Rcpp builds on top of R's C API, and it's famously great. And I know that it offers a much more pleasant programming experience interfacing R and C, provided you know C++, and Rcpp.

Comment: Sure, I find it takes a lot of tedium out and makes it possible to do more advanced things -- ie the calling back issue.  I worked that out [in RcppDE](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppde) for user-supplied objective functions _in C or C++_ that you can then pass around to the optimizer.  You could still play with this to try some mechanics before making it dependency-free which I share as a good goal.  But there are trade-offs and I also like easy of use :)  (And I experiemented [here](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/tidycpp) with another lighthweight wrapper without depends.)